# Find a necessary and sufficient condition that the real numbers $ a, b, c $ for there to be a function in $ f \in \mathcal{H}(C)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a necessary and sufficient condition that the
real numbers $ a, b, c $ for there to be a function in $ f
\in \mathcal{H}(C)$, verifying that
$ Re f(x + iy) = ax^{2} + bxy + cy^{2} $ for any $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $. Determines, when this condition is met, all integer functions $ f $ whose real part is as indicated.

We must find sufficient and necessary conditions for the real numbers $ a, b, c $ for a holomorphic function to exist in $ C $ in such a way that the required condition is fulfilled. I have started directly from the definition to verify what are the conditions that these numbers must meet for there to be a differentiable function in all $ C $, since a function is holomorphic in $ D $ if it is differentiable in all $ D $. However I have not been able to conclude anything.

Comment: $\Re f$ is harmonic so see what that condition gives you for $a,b,c$

Comment: clearly it is harmonic. However the conditions of $ a, b, c $ are not immediate for me

Comment: you need $a+c=0$ when you write $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ and then for $ax^2+bxy-ay^2$ you have a harmonic conjugate $2axy-(b/2)(x^2-y^2)$ giving the functions $az^2-i(b/2)z^2+iC, C \in \mathbb R$ arbitrary